# Python how to read output from pexpect child?

Tags: python, pexpect

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('/bin/bash')
child.sendline('ls')
print(child.readline())
print child.before, child.after
```

All I get with this code in my output is

```
ls

ls
```

But when my code is

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
print(child.readline())
print child.before, child.after
```

Then it works, but only for the first 2 prints. Am I using the wrong send command? I tried send, write, sendline, and couldn't find anymore.

Answer (score 30):

In pexpect the `before` and `after` attributes are populated after an `expect` method. The most common thing used in this situation is waiting for the prompt (so you'll know that the previous command finished execution). So, in your case, the code might look something like this:

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('/bin/bash')
child.expect("Your bash prompt here")
child.sendline('ls')
#If you are using pxssh you can use this
#child.prompt()
child.expect("Your bash prompt here")
print(child.before)
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the command that you wrote when you print `child.before`? I suppose I just trim until I see the `\r\n`.

Answer (score 21):

Try the following:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
print child.read() # not readline
```

The `read()` will give you the entire output of the ls.

Comment: also works for `spawnu` in my testing, where the other top answers did not. Might need to first verify the command has finished, although probably won't matter for `ls`.

Answer (score 15):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh root@172.16.0.120c -p 2222")
child.logfile = open("/tmp/mylog", "w")
child.expect(".*assword:")
child.send("XXXXXXX\r")
child.expect(".*\$ ")
child.sendline("ls\r")
child.expect(".*\$ ")
```

go to open your logfile:-
go to terminal

```
$gedit /tmp/mylog
```

As Per https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class

```
# In Python 3, we'll use the ``encoding`` argument to decode data
# from the subprocess and handle it as unicode:
 child = pexpect.spawn('some_command', encoding='utf-8')
 child.logfile = sys.stdout
```

Comment: this example could easily be used to phish...just sayin

Comment: open("/tmp/mylog", "wb") in python3 as we get byte as output

Comment: @Ashwani Please refer this https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class

Answer (score 7):

I think all you need is:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('ls')
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(p.before)
```

or

```
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/ls')
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(p.before)
```

or

```
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "ls"')
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(p.before)
```

or even

```
print(pexpect.run('ls'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

See [the manual entry on the subject.](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.logfile_send)

Comment: Caveat: if `child.sendline(...)` is the last line of the program, the output won't (have the time to) be captured. Expecting an EOF helps: `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)`. 
http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commonissues.html#truncated-output-just-before-child-exits

Comment: @VictorSergienko Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Couple more notes: 1. I'd assign `logfile` first. 2. Expecting EOF only works if the stream actually ends. If we're spawning a shell, we have to explicitly add `exit` as a last command.

Comment: Wasn't spawning a shell here, but that is a good point. Added the other thing, though.

Answer (score 1):

copy from class spawn(SpawnBase) docstring, maybe example-2 is what you want.

Example log input and output to a file::

```
child = pexpect.spawn('some_command')
fout = open('mylog.txt','wb')
child.logfile = fout
```

Example log to stdout::

```
# In Python 2:
child = pexpect.spawn('some_command')
child.logfile = sys.stdout

# In Python 3, we'll use the ``encoding`` argument to decode data
# from the subprocess and handle it as unicode:
child = pexpect.spawn('some_command', encoding='utf-8')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple package [tiotrap](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/tiotrap), which contains `TextIOTrap` helper class for managing TextIO Streams.

Installation:

```
python3 -m pip install tiotrap
```

For example:

```py
tio_trap = tiotrap.TextIOTrap(store=True)
p = pexpect.spawn('ls -la')
p.logfile = tio_trap
p.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(f"ls output:\n{str(tio_trap)}\n~")
```

Answer (score 0):

for me the logfile approach wasn't working as it contained a bunch of escape characters I couldn't get rid off.

I ended up echoing the cmd-output, e.g. if your OS is ubuntu:

```
child.sendline(yourcommand > logfile.txt)
```